# YouTube contact/support email?

Tags: youtube, account-recovery

I asked a question here:[Forgot YouTube account and Password](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/70123/forgot-youtube-account-and-password) but didn't get a good answer what to do. I know that this will be difficult to fix for me. So my last option is contacting YouTube and trying to get a result. But I searched for a YouTube contact email or something like that, but I only found web forms that are made for certain conditions like "forgot password", "problems signing in" or something like that.

Is there a YouTube contact email or something like that - something that lets me contact YouTube and give a detailed explanation?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to find a tech support number per se.  Google has done everything in its power to automate the process, since they would probably get millions of calls per day if they didn't.  If it's a GMail address that you registered with and you left an alternate email, they will email you a list of your Gmail accounts to the alternate.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no support email.   Your only option is to use the support forms that you found - and you will need to provide enough data to convince Google that it really was you who created the channel.